# Show disabled options using html 5 datalist

Tags: html, dropdown, datalist

I am looking to show the disabled options as a grayed out unselectable item in the list using the  tag.

When using the  tag instead of a datalist, it shows it by default. But when using datalist, it hides it by default. I would like to use datalist for the searchable dropdown menu.

The actual goal of the datalist is to logically group items in a single list where only the items are selectable and not the group name

Example:

- **Group 1**
- Item 1
- Item 2
- **Group 2**
- Item 1
- Item 2